# Is there any exchange that offers a Monero/Aeon trading pair?

Tags: exchange, aeon, cryptopia, poloniex, bittrex

Aeon is the cleanest fork of Monero and shares a developer and some community members. Are there any exchanges where Monero can be traded for Aeon directly without the need to use Bitcoin as an intermediary currency for the exchange?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently there are two exchanges that offer direct XMR/AEON conversion each with its own limitations/warnings. The third option would be direct OTC trades (optionally with an escrow agent to reduce risk).

1. [Cryptopia](https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Exchange/?market=AEON_XMR) offers the most XMR trading pairs of any exchange including an XMR/AEON pair. Its current limitation is very low trading volume compared to the [Poloniex](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.msg12018758#msg12018758) (first exchange that offered Monero trading pairs including XMR/AEON previously).
2. [Changelly](https://changelly.com/) operates in a manner similar to Shapeshift but unlike Shapeshift offers Aeon trading and direct XMR/AEON conversion. It receives a large level of [distrust](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4rb2b6/has_anyone_used_changellycom_to_convert_btc_to_xmr/d4zqku8) within the Monero community due to its connection with Minergate
3. There is a Bitcointalk thread designed to connect buyers and sellers hoping to arrange [OTC trades](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4rb2b6/has_anyone_used_changellycom_to_convert_btc_to_xmr/d4zqku8). IRC trading at ​#monero-otc is another option
4. [LocalMonero](https://localmonero.co) also provides an OTC platform for XMR/AEON trades.

The centralized exchange with the most Aeon volume is Bittrex. It was not mentioned in my answer above because they do not offer a XMR/AEON trading pair. Bittrex does offer both a [BTC/XMR](https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-XMR) trading pair and a [BTC/AEON](https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-AEON) trading pair.